# ¿Cómo deshabilitar un botón si un SELECT e INPUT están vacíos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario con tres input[type="text"], un select y su botón de envío.

Estoy intentando deshabilitar el botón de envío del formulario, SI los **INPUTS** y el **SELECT** están vacíos únicamente. En otras palabras:

-Lleno el input uno (botón deshabilitado),
-Lleno el input dos  (botón deshabilitado),
-Lleno el select (botón habilitado) -porque están llenos  todos-

pero en caso de que en alguno de los elementos borren (quede vació), el botón se inhabilite.
Alguno idea de como se puede lograr eso?

Comment: Bienvenido, te invito a hacer el [tour] y de paso checar [ask], te comento que sería genial si pudieras añadir lo que has hecho o investigado hasta el momento así como los errores específicos que has tenido, de modo que la comunidad sepa desde que parte comenzar a ayudarte :D

Answer (score 0):

te refieres eventos para validar si están vacíos los campos. acá una solución, donde al ir llenando los campos, se logra habilitar el botón de envio

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Validación del formulario al ser llenado
  $("input[type=text], select").change(function(){
    $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', false).attr('title','Habilitado para enviar *');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<label for="input_1">Input #1:<label/>
<input id = "input_1" type="text">
<label for="input_2" type="text">Input #2:<label/>
<input id = "input_2">
<select>
  <option><option>
  <option>value 1<option>
  <option>value 2<option>
<select/>
<input type="submit" id="Send form" disabled title="Debe llenar los campos *">
</form>
```

Comment: Hola, no exactamente. (edite la pregunta). Lo que busco es:

-Lleno el input uno (botón deshabilitado), -Lleno el input dos (botón deshabilitado), -Lleno el select (botón habilitado) -porque están llenos todos- pero en caso de que en alguno de los elementos borren (quede vació), el botón se inhabilite. Ahí esta lo complicado para mi

Comment: Okay, Allí puedes mantener la función onChange que te compartí, y se adicionas la validación del valor, algo como, Si input o select cambia(lo que ya tienes) y valor != ' ' habilita el botón

Comment: @No doy con el chiste. No logro hacerlo con condicionales, algo me falta no se que sea

Comment: Sucede que funciona si lleno el input 1, luego el 2 y el botón se activa. Debe permanecer desactivado si no se ah seleccionado en el select. Y es lo que no logro hacer